# How can I increase virtual box window

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I am running virtual box on Windows 7. And I have installed an 'Ubuntu server' guest as one of my machine. Since it is a server guest, it just gives me a prompt to login when I start the machine.

My question is how can I increase the size of the VirualBox window so that I can have a bigger shell to access the 'Ubuntu gust'.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer to this [here](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/coffee-lounge/160356-virtualbox-console-only-linux.html) when I was looking. It details setting the framebuffer size in GRUB to manipulate the size of your console window.

Comment: Thanks. but where is the 'grub.cfg' file?

Comment: `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Be CAREFUL. Making the wrong changes will render your system unbootable. Read twice, write once.